# port forwarding to internal lan server

Tags: linux, iptables

I've ppp0 --> eth1 and eth0 (internal lan). I need forwarding externel 10022 port to port 8999 of the server 192.168.1.254

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i ppp0 --dport 10022 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.254:8999
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.254 --dport 10022 -j ACCEPT
```

I also have:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ppp0/forwarding 

1
```

connection time-out... any idea?

iptables -L -nv

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 14 packets, 1609 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  -f  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID 
 2037  136K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  tap0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   14  1609 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           LOG flags 0 level 4 

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      ppp2    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x06/0x02 tcpmss match 1400:1536 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU 
    0     0 TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x06/0x02 tcpmss match 1400:1536 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU 
    0     0 TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x06/0x02 tcpmss match 1400:1536 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU 
    0     0 TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      ppp0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x06/0x02 tcpmss match 1400:1536 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU 
   16  2368 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.0/24      state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           LOG flags 0 level 4 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  -f  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID 
 3097 4268K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: whole bunch of useful examples for iptables here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/scripts/iptables-rules

Comment: also give us other policy details using `iptables -L -n -v`

Comment: Can you telnet to 192.168.1.254 8999. `telnet 192.168.1.254 8999`. Also type `netstat -ntl` and post the output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set IP forwarding on eth0 too. Use

```
sysctl -p net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

The -p makes the change persistent over reboots. Also, I could be wrong, but I thought the top line should be :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i ppp0 --dport 10022 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.254:8999
```

Comment: Hi and thanks. I already have IP fw to eth0. Also modify with your line, does not work.

Comment: you can abbreviate the iptables options. --to is the same as --to-destination